# Map for tree items

Tags: java, gwt

i build a tree with uibinder, and want to get this:

```
-tree1
treeel1
treeel2
+tree2
-tree3
element
```

what i defined on xml:

```
...
                        <g:Tree ui:field='tree'>
                             <g:TreeItem ui:field='treeEl'>
                                <g:Tree ui:field='tree1'>
                                    <g:TreeItem ui:field='subTreeEl'>
                                    </g:TreeItem>
                                </g:Tree> 
                            </g:TreeItem> 
                        </g:Tree>
                    ....
```

on client i have this:

```
void treework() {
 AsyncCallback<Map<Data,List<Value>>> callback=new AsyncCallback<Map<Data,List<Value>>>() {

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Map<Data, List<Value>> result) {

            for (Entry<Data, List<Value>> it : result
                    .entrySet()) {


                treeEl= new TreeItem();


                String key = String.valueOf(it.getKey().getName());
                List<Value> list = it.getValue();
                treeEl.setText(key);

                for (Value v: list) {

                    subTreeEl = new TreeItem();
                    subTreeEl.setText(v.getName());
                    tree1.addItem(subTreeEl);

                }

                subTreeEl.setState(true, true);
                treeEl.setState(true, true);
                treeEl.addItem(tree1);
                tree.addItem(treeEl);



            }

        }
    };

 rpcService.getData(callback);
}
```

i get after running all this is the tree with items but all inneritems is within the last tree value like this:

```
+tree1
+tree2
-tree3
 treeel1
 treeel2
 element
```

what i am doing wrong, any suggestions? i want to get a tree element for each treeitem name, with the map of the list of elements to the data name

Comment: +1 for including code, desired output, and actual output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the data to add is dynamic, modify your xml file as:

```
                    <g:Tree ui:field='tree'>
                    </g:Tree>
```

And the client code for adding data to tree as follows:

```
for (Entry<Data, List<Value>> it : result.entrySet()) {

            TreeItem treeEl= new TreeItem();

            String key = String.valueOf(it.getKey().getName());
            List<Value> list = it.getValue();
            treeEl.setText(key);

            for (Value v: list) {

                TreeItem subTreeEl = new TreeItem();
                subTreeEl.setText(v.getName());
                treeEl.addItem(subTreeEl);

            }

            treeEl.setState(true, true);
            tree.addItem(treeEl);
}
```